# Sitecore redirecting to federated authentication provider on unauthorized

Tags: federated-authentication

I have a Sitecore 9 site configured to use an OWIN provider as described in [this article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/federated_authentication/configure_federated_authentication). The site also allows users to authenticate via forms authentication. The two authentication methods are working at this point.

Here's the issue: Whenever a user hits a page that they are unauthorized to view, Sitecore immediately redirects them to the OWIN providers's login page. What we need instead is for Sitecore to display a custom 403 Unauthorized page with relevant information. We have installed the plugin "Sitecore Error Manager", so we already have the ability to display a 403 page.

How do we change this behavior and tell Sitecore to redirect to our 403 page instead of the federated auth login page?

Comment: Is this sitecore 9? Very strange it's redirecting to provider without any interaction

Comment: Yes, it is Sitecore 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't a Sitecore issue - it was an MVC issue. The redirects to the login page were occuring when we hit a controller decorated with [Authorize] that we weren't authorized for.

To change this behavior, we extended the Authorize attribute and set a custom redirect URL like this: https://forums.asp.net/t/2039316.aspx?Change+redirect+page+when+user+is+unauthorized

Answer (score 3):

You can set the NoAccessUrl setting or the loginPage attribute on the sitedefinition to point to your custom page. This [article](http://josedbaez.com/2018/03/sitecore9-sso/) has an example of using the NoAccessUrl to point to a custom page.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't solve the issue. Sitecore redirects to the federated site's login page no matter what I set for the site definition's "loginPage" value. I've ensured that it's using the right site definition by appending sc_site=website to the URL with the same result.
Same goes for NoAccessUrl. It already had a value - "/sitecore modules/Web/Error Manager/403.aspx?key=NoAccessUrl - due to the Sitecore Error Manager plugin.

Comment: Jeroen, we are still facing this problem. We are running Sitecore 9 update-1. Do you know if this issue was addressed in the Sitecore 9 update-2 release? It seems to me like an internal error of some sort.

Comment: Not sure if anything related to this was addressed in update 2. This is working for me in Sitecore 9 update 1.